# How can i fix Django Postgresql migrations error?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I can import migrations with Sqlite3 in my Django project, but when I try to import it with postgreql, I get an error like this. How can I fix this?

I installed before

```
pip install psycopg2
pip install django psycopg2
```

Error

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

DB Settings Django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'lordplusdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following value for the engine:
`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'`

The added `_psycopg2` is for older versions of Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-3-0